# How can I avoid double submissions with pushState and $.ajax(hash) in non-IE browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pushstate, jquery-bbq

Internet Explorer appears to be the only major browser that does not support pushState to handle history for AJAX submissions. So everywhere I have:

```
$.bbq.pushState(hash);
```

in my AJAX code, I have to add another line:

```
$.ajax(hash);
```

This of course causes a double-submission in all non-IE browsers that DO support submission via pushState().

What can I do to avoid these double submissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call `$.ajax(hash);` in a conditional statement only if the `history.pushState` is not natively supported

```
if (!history.pushState) {
   $.ajax(hash);
}
```

I also suggest to refactor your code using a unique wrapper function accepting an hash as parameter with the necessary logic, e.g.

```
var pushStateWrapper = function(hash) {

    if (!history.pushState) {
       $.ajax(hash);
    }
    else {
       $.bbq.pushState(hash);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great. Yeah, I will need to refactor. Do I then just call pushStateWrapper with my hash? pushStateWrapper(hash);

Comment: yes, this is the purpose (of course I could have oversimplified the code, is just to get you the idea)